# Configure a load test to return 10 TPS throughput for an Async API with expected response time of 500 ms in Jmeter

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, throughput

How can we configure  a load test script to achieve 10 TPS throughput for an Async API with expected response time of 500 ms in Jmeter.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Here are some performance stats from one of the runs for this API ( create asset response ):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99A0I.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. 10 TPS throughput:

   - you need to make sure to provide enough threads (virtual users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) in order to reach this 10 TPS throughput. If you expect response time not more than 500 ms 5 users should be sufficient.
   - in case if 5 users will be creating more throughput than 10 TPS you can limit it by using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput)
2. 500 ms expected response time. Add [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) and set "Duration in milliseconds" to 500. If any Sampler in the Assertion's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) will take more than 500 ms it will be marked as failed